# What is the difference between 嫌{きら}う and 嫌{いや}がる?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between 嫌{きら}う and 嫌{いや}がる? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a good example of a pair of words that would seem interchangeable if "translated" as both are often just translated to "to hate".

「嫌う」 and 「嫌がる」 are only "casually" interchangeable but not strictly so.  The key word is 「がる」, not the big kanji 「嫌」.

For instance, you can hate your husband without anyone knowing it, including your husband.  To keep it a secret, all you have to do is to be a good actress and not show your true feelings.  This is 「嫌う」.

If your hatred toward your hubby ever starts showing in your words or attitude, we are getting into the realm of 「嫌がる」.  There is "evidence" now.

Comment: 〇「TNは、嫌がる彼女を無理やり・・・」 ×「TNは、嫌う彼女を無理やり・・・」〇「やめたまえ、TNくん！ちよこさんが嫌がっているじゃないか。」　×「やめたまえ、TNくん！ちよこさんが嫌っているじゃないか。」